# "Don't do that" is not a constructive response

Tags: discussion, welcoming

In the wake of the "SO is not very welcoming" blog post, I'd like to draw attention to another kind of comment that drives people away - at least, anecdotally.  Let's take a look at a random question:

[What's the best way of implementing a buffer of fixed size when using fread in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26369110/whats-the-best-way-of-implementing-a-buffer-of-fixed-size-when-using-fread-in-c)

The questioner is obviously knowledgeable enough about the subject: he understands the terms in use, he has thought through some possibilities for implementation, and he needs someone with a bit more expertise to confirm his options.

Yet, the top-rated comment:
"My question would be why are you using fread in C++?"

---

This sort of "don't do that" answer is all too common on SO questions.  Yes, there are some times when the user is clearly trying to hammer a nail with a screwdriver - but more often, the commenter is just knee-jerk reacting to keywords in the post, bypassing the intent of the question.  "Oh!  This post is tagged C++, but has no mention of iostream.  'WHY ARE YOU DOING IT WRONG?'  Looks like my job here is done."

Who is helped by this?  Would we be better served by e.g. a bot that just auto-comments to any post tagged "optimization" with "Did you profile your code?"  Or one that drops by a post tagged "iOS 7" and says "iOS 7 is outdated, why don't you update?"  Or one that trawls the XML posts and says "Why not switch to JSON?"  ... As though the OP hadn't already considered these "solutions" and rejected them, for reasons unrelated to their question?

---

Comments like this put the asker on the defensive.  They make the blatant assumption that the OP is completely ignorant, and force them to "prove" their worthiness in asking.  This does nothing but reinforce the idea that SO is full of elitist answerers.

Comment: "My question would be why are you using fread in C++?" != "WHY ARE YOU DOING IT WRONG?"

Comment: As for what solutions the OP has already considered unless they are explicitly mentioned in the question, how's anyone to know?

Comment: If there are more conventional ways in a technology to achieve the same goal, I am happy to hear them. Especially in C++, you often aren't taught these in school/university.

Comment: The accepted(!) answer starts with: 'I would use neither of your examples'. Is this not constructive, too?

Comment: My understanding of this meta post is that you would rather the comment say something like "fread is not a good tool to do what you want; you would be better off refactoring to use an entirely different approach." Is that roughly correct?

Comment: So someone about to leave themselves open to an SQL injection attack shouldn't be told 'no, don't do that!'? we should help them load the gun they have pointed at their foot? That feels.... Even worse. I can be elitist/condescending/unwelcoming and help them understand what is happening.... Or I can help them mess up their whole application.

Comment: Essential reading on the underlying theme: [*What is the XY problem?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) (MSE). Asking "Why are you doing Y?" is sometimes necessary to figure out whether or not the asker has a XY problem, and knowing that is key to providing useful answers. (See also: the answers by Kendra and Makoto here.)

Comment: "_Don't do that_" is very constructive response (even in an answer) at the place where it belongs. It is used when the OP really shouldn't do what they are doing, or an incorrect answer is proposing. It shouldn't be used without an explanantion, though.

Answer (score 36):

In some, possibly many, cases, the OP *hasn't* considered these options. These comments are part of helping make sure the question isn't an XY problem. If the OP has a clear reason they can't use the standard methods, and they've already tried those, they really should have that in the question to help make it clear.

Honestly, sometimes, we as professional developers can get a little code blind. I know of countless times I've tried to do something one way, only to realize halfway through debugging a painful part of it that there was a simpler, standard option all along. Usually, a coworker has to point this "obvious" solution out to me. I've similarly pointed these "obvious" solutions out to coworkers countless times. We can get so wrapped up in a problem that we lose sight of the forest for the trees.

These comments are doing what comments are made for: Seeking clarification. You want to use VB.NET to do something with your HTML and return it? Why are you doing this rather than JavaScript? You may well have a completely valid reason that we don't know, but we will continue not to know unless you explicitly tell us.

We aren't mind readers. A lot of us are in this to help the OP with their problem. If their problem seems like it could be solved a different way, why wouldn't we want to see if we can help them avoid further pitfalls? And wouldn't you rather have an easy to get rid of comment asking why someone isn't using something than have someone assert in an answer that the OP should be using that solution instead?

Also note that these aren't *"don't do that"* comments; these are *"why are you doing that"* comments. They aren't saying *"don't drive a nail with a screwdriver"*, but instead *"why not use a hammer for this?"* The answer to that question might well be *"My employer refuses to allow us the use of hammers"* or *"Hammers are too expensive in my area"* or what have you, or the answer might be, *"Oh! A hammer! Why didn't I think of that?"* Either way, some sort of clarification is achieved, and no one is expressly told they *can't* do what they're asking about. That's all we want.

Answer (score 24):

Programming gives you a lot of freedom and liberty, and there are a multitude of ways to solve problems.

Hearing a justification as to why one chose the approach they did is valuable for a couple of reasons:

- It gives us insight into their requirements or constraints.
- It informs our answers.
- It makes sure that the OP isn't just blindly copying code from the Internet and trying to glue it together. (This is more for *their* benefit, but it's manifest here anyway.)

Take [this question for example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29727655/1079354).  No one in any mental state should be using Java 1.2 right now, but there are some people that *have* to.  Asking "why" would likely merit a response of, "No choice", **which is fine**.  The OP in that question could also reply along the lines of that and then either be enlightened in another approach on how to accomplish what it is they're looking to do or illustrate their operating constraints.

I would **discourage you from being defensive** when someone asks you to justify what you're doing.  It's not the language's responsibility to stop you from coiling rope around your neck and jumping off of a cliff.  But when you ask for help, *understandably* you're going to get some people asking you why you're coiling the rope *there* in the first place if you just wanted to rappel off of the cliff.